# BFS ever failing for a unweighted and undirected graph?

Tags: algorithm, breadth-first-search

So I am just doing some work for my algorithms class and I was just wonder does a BFS tree ever fail on finding the single source shortest path I know that BFS finds the shortest path with the least amount of edges and I am pretty convinced BFS never fails on a unweighted graph

Ive drew multiple graphs by hand and the bfs graph and they all have turned out to be the single single source shortest path.

Comment: Rather than asking here, you'll be much better off if you can prove it to yourself rigorously. One approach to a proof is to look at the point in the BFS where a node is found. Then assume that there is some other path from the source with fewer edges that reaches the same node. Finally explain why that assumption must be false. This gives you a proof by contradiction that BFS always works.

Comment: The BFS algorithm guarantees to find the shortest path from the source vertex to any other connected vertex in the graph.

Answer (score 0):

I think that BFS never fails to find the shortest path because BFS:

- assumes that all edges weight equal to 1.
- it guarantees because it processes nodes sequentially. And [it means we are going to find all the vertices that are one edge away first and then all the vertices are two edge away. And then all the vertices that are three edge away and so on](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T_m27bhVQQQ)

Comment: *"left child has less distance to the destination than right child"*: I don't get what "left" and "right" mean in a graph. Also, what if the "right" child was the target? Then surely this statement is false.

Comment: @trincot thank you for your comment! I've a little bit restated what I mean. Please, see my updated answer

Comment: Alright. I would suggest "vertices" instead of "things", and "one edge" and "two edges" instead of just "one" and "two" -- same for "three". And instead of linking to YouTube, why not link to some more reputable source?

Comment: @trincot thank you for all your great advices. I’ve linked YouTube because this video shows with animations how it works and what arrays are updated during traversal. If there is better source, I would be happy to see other greater explanations! :)

Answer (score -2):

Yeah, BFS will absolutely fail on an unweighted and undirected graph; you just have to use too much memory...